# Magento 2: Data migration Class error

Tags: magento2.2, data-migration

I tried to migrate data from Magento 1.9.2.2 to Magento 2.2.2 for testing. I am getting below error

> [2018-02-14 11:45:37][INFO][mode: data][stage: volume check][step: EAV Step]: started
>   100% [============================] Remaining Time: < 1 sec
>
> [2018-02-14 11:45:37][ERROR]: Class Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Helper\Form\BaseImage does not exist but mentioned in: catalog_eav_attribute.frontend_input_renderer for attribute_id=74

I already tried after adding below in **class-map.xml.dist** but it didn't work.

```
<rename>
    <from>Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Helper\Form\BaseImage</from>
    <to />
</rename>
```

Comment: All Magento 1 Core Classes should have corespondents in Magento 2 out of the box. Is this class nativ Magento1 core Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Helper\Form\BaseImage or did someone put it there

Comment: saeme happening to me,[0;31m[2018-05-29 11:28:36][ERROR]: Class Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Helper\Form\BaseImage does not exist but mentioned in: catalog_eav_attribute.frontend_input_renderer for attribute_id=106[0m

Comment: I am also facing the same, someone got solution for this?

Comment: Have u resolve the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

In the `catalog_eav_attribute` table, there are entries directing to specific classes.

The image class path was first named:

> Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Helper\Form\BaseImage

But is now called:

> Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Helper\Form\Image